# Swift: Create multiple views through iteration with spacing without using StackView

Tags: arrays, swift

I'm trying to create multiple labels with padding of 20 between each item without using stackView. My current logic has them all aligned on top of each other. Any thoughts whats wrong with the current code? Im not seeing it.

```
 let sections = ["List", "Items", "News"]

var previousLabel: UILabel?
var sectionsArray = [UILabel]()
var leadConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?

let navigationView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 100, width: 100, height: 30))

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    view.backgroundColor = .black
    
    view.addSubview(navigationView)
    navigationView.backgroundColor = .red
    
    for label in sections {
        let newLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect.zero)
        newLabel.text = label
        newLabel.textColor = .white
        newLabel.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        newLabel.sizeToFit()
        navigationView.addSubview(newLabel)
        
        
        if let previous = previousLabel {
            
            leadConstraint = newLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: previous.rightAnchor, constant: 20)
            leadConstraint?.isActive = true
            newLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navigationView.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
            newLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navigationView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        } else {
            
            //1st item in section
            newLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navigationView.leftAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
            newLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navigationView.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
            newLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navigationView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        }
        sectionsArray.append(newLabel)
        previousLabel = newLabel
    }
```

[image]

This is a image of the error message, i couldnt make out what exactly what constraint was having a problem.

[image]

Comment: Did you notice the error messages in the Xcode console? They provide a major clue.

Comment: @matt i edited the post to add image of error message. but i wasnt sure what exactly was it. Error message was super long.

Comment: But still it is shouting the answer at you, as loud as it knows how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
let newLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect.zero)
```

To

```
let newLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect.zero)
newLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

This will expose other flaws in your implementation, but at least the labels will line up horizontally in the way you expect.

Comment: That was it!!!! thanks. Forgot to add it in and wasnt see it! :D

Comment: And yet the Console was telling you.

Comment: May i ask what other flaws will it expose? I usually get that error message when my views werent anchoring correctly, but this time, it saw that my anchoring was correct so i wasnt sure what was exactly the problem. Thank you for pointing out about translateAutoResizing, ill make a note of that!

Comment: Well, for example, the relationship between the labels and the red navigation view that contains them is probably not coming out the way you intended.